# JavaFX - How do you add multiple elements to a StackPane?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX. I'm trying to create a simple centred menu that contains text with buttons below.

I've created two elements, `Text title` and `Button testButton`. Then I created `StackPane stackPane`. I'm then trying to add the two elements to the `stackPanes` children and adding that to a `new Scene`. However, only the last element shows up.

How can I add multiple elements to the StackPane?

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Test Title");

    Text title = new Text("hey!");
    StackPane.setAlignment(title, Pos.TOP_CENTER);

    Button testButton = new Button("Testing");
    StackPane.setAlignment(testButton, Pos.TOP_CENTER);

    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
    stackPane.setPrefSize(300, 300);
    stackPane.setPadding(new Insets(25, 0, 0, 0));

    stackPane.getChildren().add(title);
    stackPane.getChildren().add(testButton);

    Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

[image]

Comment: They're both there, they're just stacked one on top of the other (which is how a `StackPane` lays out it child nodes). Just use a layout pane that lays them out the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to reference the official documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html, especially:

> StackPane lays out its children in a back-to-front stack.
>   The z-order of the children is defined by the order of the children list with the 0th child being the bottom and last child on top. If a border and/or padding have been set, the children will be layed out within those insets.

Now, to answer your question: You do it as you did, but you probably want an offset as both the children are at the same position, hence the one later added is overlaying all the previous ones.

You can check that by changing e.g.

`Text title = new Text("Adding a very, very, very, very, very, very long text here... now that vile button should not overlap me anymore!");`

or setting the alignment differently.

If you don't want to bother with the optimal layout by manually positioning, it's probably better to use another `Pane` that does that for you, e.g. one of the direct known subclasses here: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/layout/Pane.html

Comment: Note also http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102